# Taking the address of a two dimensional array's element

Tags: arrays, pointers, instance, crystal-lang

I been trying to follow the [Crystal specification](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.7/syntax_and_semantics/pointerof.html). It shows an example of taking the address of an instance variable. So I have an analogue function, but pointing to an instance of a 2d array

```rb
def map_ptr(x : Int32, y : Int32)
  pointerof(@map[x][y])
end
```

where the `@map` array is defined somehow similar to:

```rb
@map = Array(Array(Room)).new(SIZE) { Array(Room).new(SIZE, Room.new) }
    
(0...SIZE).each do |x|
  (0...SIZE).each do |y|
    room_type = ROOMS.sample
    @map[x][y] = Room.new(room_type)
  end
end
```

When I try to use the `map_ptr` function in  a assignment like: `current_room = map_ptr(0, 0)`, the Crystal compiler gives me an error that says only:

```
Error: can't take address of @map[x][y]
```

Why does it say `@map[x][y]` and not `Room`, which is the actual type it should point to? And what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I do understand that I am referencing the address of `@map[x][y]`, not the actual element it is holding. But how can I send to `pointerof()` the array's element itself?

Comment: One can just use an intermediate variable to store the value of `@map[x][y]` and then pass it to `pointerof()`. Is that the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@map[x][y]` is a call to `Array#[]`. You're trying to take the pointer address of its return value. That value is never assigned anywhere, so it doesn't have an address.

I assume you actually want to get the address of the element `x, y` inside the `@map` array.
First of all, you should be aware that this is an unsafe operation. `Array` can reallocate its items, so pointers inside it can be invalidated when adding items.
If you don't intent to add items, perhaps it would be better use `Slice` instead because that has more stability guarantees.

Both `Array` and `Slice` have a `#to_unsafe` method which returns a pointer to the first item. Then it's just `@map.to_unsafe[x].to_unsafe + y` to get a pointer inside the second dimension.

Example with `Slice`:

```
class Room
end
SIZE = 5

map = Slice(Slice(Room)).new(SIZE) { Slice(Room).new(SIZE, Room.new) }
    
map.to_unsafe[3].to_unsafe + 2 # => Pointer(Room)@0x7f80a2b58e80
```

Comment: Thank you. And then to get the value from that pointer I need to call it like, `p.value.value`. Is that correct?

Comment: As I try to dereference it I get a compile time error: `Error: undefined method 'value' for Room (compile-time type is (Pointer(Room) | Room))`

Comment: No, it would be just one `#value` call: `(map.to_unsafe[3].to_unsafe + 2).value`. Or just `map.to_unsafe[3].to_unsafe[2]`.
I don't know how you managed to get the union `(Pointer(Room) | Room)`. Seems to be something wrong in your code.